# What is "ZK" type in Kafka Consumer Page

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to Kafka. I am seeing same consumer in different types (KF or ZK).
Is ZK necessary? If not, how can I remove that?

Consumer page:

[image: Consumer Page]

Comment: I don't know what UI this is, but Zookeeper is a requirement for Kafka deployments

Answer (score 1):

As of Kafka 0.9, there was the addition of the ["new consumer API" that removed the dependency on Zookeeper](https://www.confluent.io/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-the-new-apache-kafka-0-9-consumer-client/)

Based on what you're seeing, the only way to remove them is to upgrade the consumer code.